# How can scipy.weave.inline be used in a MPI-enabled application on a cluster?

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-computing, mpi

If scipy.weave.inline is called inside a massive parallel MPI-enabled application that is run on a cluster with a home-directory that is common to all nodes, every instance accesses the same catalog for compiled code: $HOME/.pythonxx_compiled. This is bad for obvious reasons and leads to many error messages. How can this problem be circumvented?

Comment: I have a solution, but I am not yet allowed to post it. Other solutions are still welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous thoughts about this problem:

Either scipy.weave.catalog has to be enhanced with a proper locking mechanism in order to serialize access to the catalog, or every instance has to use its own catalog.

I chose the latter. The `scipy.weave.inline` function uses a catalog which is bound to the module-level name `function_catalog` of the `scipy.weave.inline` module. This can be discovered by looking into the code of this module (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/v0.12.0/scipy/weave).

The simples solution is now to monkeypatch this name to something else at the beginning of the program:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

import numpy as np

import scipy.weave.inline_tools
import scipy.weave.catalog

import os
import os.path

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

catalog_dir = os.path.join(some_path,  'rank'+str(rank))
try:
    os.makedirs(catalog_dir)
except OSError:
    pass

#monkeypatching the catalog
scipy.weave.inline_tools.function_catalog = scipy.weave.catalog.catalog(catalog_dir)
```

Now `inline` works smoothly: Each instance has its own catalog inside the common NFS directory. Of course this naming scheme breaks if two distinct parallel tasks ran at the same time, but this would also be the case if the catalog was in /tmp.

**Edit**: As mentioned in a comment above this procedure still bears problems if multiple indepedent jobs are run in parallel. This can be remedied by adding a random uuid to the pathname:

```
import uuid

u = None
if rank == 0:
    u = str(uuid.uuid4())

u = comm.scatter([u]*size, root=0)

catalog_dir = os.path.join('/tmp/<username>/pythoncompiled',  u+'-'+str(rank))
os.makedirs(catalog_dir)

#monkeypatching the catalog
scipy.weave.inline_tools.function_catalog = scipy.weave.catalog.catalog(catalog_dir)
```

Of course it would be nice to delete those files after the computation:

```
shutil.rmtree(catalog_dir)
```

**Edit**: There were some additional problems. The intermediate directory where cpp and o files are stored also hat some trouble due to simultaneous access from different instances, so the above method has to be extended to this directory:

```
basetmp = some_path
catalog_dir = os.path.join(basetmp, 'pythoncompiled',  u+'-'+str(rank))
intermediate_dir = os.path.join(basetmp, 'pythonintermediate',  u+'-'+str(rank))

os.makedirs(catalog_dir, mode=0o700)
os.makedirs(intermediate_dir, mode=0o700)

#monkeypatching the catalog and intermediate_dir
scipy.weave.inline_tools.function_catalog = scipy.weave.catalog.catalog(catalog_dir)
scipy.weave.catalog.intermediate_dir = lambda: intermediate_dir

#... calculations here ...

shutil.rmtree(catalog_dir)
shutil.rmtree(intermediate_dir)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [the scipy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/weave.html#catalog-search-paths-and-the-pythoncompiled-variable), you could store your compiled data in a directory that isn't on the NFS share (such as /tmp or /scratch or whatever is available for your system). Then you wouldn't have to worry about your conflicts. You just need to set the PYTHONCOMPILED environment variable to something else.

Comment: In my case this solution is simpler and more straightforward than my own solution. I will still post my solution in a few hours.

Comment: I am afraid I have to unaccept your answer. It does not solve the problem if there are multiple instances running on different processors of the same node.

Answer (score 0):

One quick workaround is to use a local directory on each node (e.g. /tmp as Wesley said), but use one MPI task per node, if you have the capacity.